# Can I add these rules "as-is" into my httpd.conf?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Here are all my rules with comments:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    # prevent directory browsing
    Options All -Indexes

    # prevent access to htaccess files anywhere on the site
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

    # prevent DIRECT access to the /inc/ directory and its PHP files
    <Files ~ "\.inc$">
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

    # custom error documents
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html

    # security requirement of the rewrite engine
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # turn on rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    # remove PHP extension
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/images>
    # caching
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">
            ExpiresDefault "modification plus 1 year"
            Header set Cache-Control: "public, max-age=31536000"
            Header unset Last-Modified
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    # turn on rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    # if file cannot be found
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /empty.jpg [NC,L]
</Directory>
```

Can I add these rules as they are to the bottom of my httpd.cnf? Or are there any mistakes? Or anything else I need to pay attention to? I don't want to screw anything up, even tho I'm just running my code on my localhost.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Put it there, restart apache, and watch if it spits out any errors about some lines in httpd.conf. That's the best way to find out.

Comment: No errors. But now the rules aren't working. I should probably just leave them in my htaccess file. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put them in `httpd.cnf` file! and they will work! The only thing you should pay attention is that to put them in right place(e.g in right site)